# R: rvest: How to use ifelse for nodes?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scrapping this page:

https://www.linio.com.pe/c/tv-y-video/televisores

And I want to extract the current price of the TVs. The problem is that some prices are inside a `<div>` and others -fewer- inside a `<span>` tag.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use an 'ifelse' construct to get all the current prices for the TVs.

```
#Reads Linio's HTML

linio <- read_html("https://www.linio.com.pe/c/tv-y-video/televisores", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")


#Extracts prices inside the div tag


linio %>% html_nodes("div.price-section div.price-secondary") %>% html_text()


#Extracts prices inside the span tag

linio %>% html_nodes("div.price-section span.price-secondary") %>% html_text()
```

I was trying this to combine the prices from the div and the span tags:

```
linio %>% ifelse(length(html_nodes("div.price-section div.price-secondary") %>% html_text())==0, html_nodes("div.price-section span.price-secondary") %>% html_text(), html_nodes("div.price-section div.price-secondary")) %>% html_text()
```

Without success... why can't you be consistant Linio's front end developers...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish that:

**Drop the `div`/`span` altogether using:**

```
linio %>% html_nodes("div.price-section .price-secondary") %>% html_text()
```

This selects all elements with class `price-secondary` inside
   `div.price-section`.

**More specific**
Only select `div` and `span` tags inside `div.price-section` you can use:

```
linio %>% 
  html_nodes("div.price-section div.price-secondary, div.price-section span.price-secondary") %>% 
  html_text
```

For a full CSS selector reference see
   https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

**minimal CSS selector**
To find a minimal CSS selector have a look at http://selectorgadget.com/

In your case this would be:

```
   linio %>% html_nodes(".price-secondary") %>% html_text
```

This selects all elements with class `price-secondary`

**Test that all return the same result**

```
res1 <- linio %>% html_nodes("div.price-section .price-secondary") %>% html_text()
res2 <- linio %>% 
  html_nodes("div.price-section div.price-secondary, div.price-section span.price-secondary") %>% 
  html_text
res3 <- linio %>% html_nodes(".price-secondary") %>% html_text
all(res1 == res2) # TRUE 
all(res2 == res3) # TRUE
```